# why no overflow when char is more than one byte?

Tags: c++

if char is only 1 byte (8bit, 255 max size), how 65534th char can be saved in char ?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned wchar_t a = 65534;
    char b = (char)a;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

also in java you can write `byte b = 5000;`
do anyone knows why ?

Comment: In Java you cannot write `byte b = 5000;`

Comment: Looks like it is 2 different questions. Better to ask them separately.

Comment: if byte size is 8 bit, why no overflow when using code byte b = 5000; ?

Comment: Who said there was no overflow?

Comment: sorry, u can write byte b = (byte)5000;

Comment: there is an overflow, and high order bits are just thrown away

Comment: This `byte b = (byte)5000;` causes a truncation of the value, rather than oveflow IMHO.

Comment: The overflow occurs, but it does not cause any runtime notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the C++ code, the `wchar_t` value gets truncated to fit in the `char` variable. Normally there would be a warning from the compiler about this loss of data, but by using the C-style cast you've told the compiler "don't worry, I know what I'm doing" and taken responsibility for the consequences of your (questionable) actions.

Comment: so how can i save 65534th char ? i mean what type of variable ?

Comment: @Giorgi: Probably a `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, or a `char32_t`

Comment: Why don't you just keep it in a `wchar_t`?

Comment: @Giorgi: In C++, a `char` is either a byte, or an ASCII character.  If you're dealing with non-ASCII, don't use `char`.  Use `char32_t` or a string.

Comment: and also, what type to use in java for it ?

Comment: @MooingDuck can u help me ?

Comment: @Giorgi: In Java, you would use an `int`, they don't have a (useful) built in type that can _store_ arbitrary character code points.